# System.OverflowException when running dtsserver.getrunningpackages()

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm having a sudden error in a SQL-Server agent job that runs an SSIS package:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.OverflowException:
>   Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Server.DtsServer.RunningPackageConvert(RunningPackage
>   package, DTSRunningPackage100& copy) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Server.DtsServer.GetRunningPackages()

Relevant code in SSIS:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
RunningPackages pkgs = app.GetRunningPackages(null);
```

Looks similar to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/dc5a3584-5cf0-4a4c-b35d-9d80ff8ec149) (no solution mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

After struggling many days.I've found the solution at last.

**Root Cause:**

The MsDtsSrvr.exe is the root for all SSIS Service.The MsDtsSrvr.exe memory will grow continuously for every SSIS packages that run on that machine.

The RunningPackages class will try to get the all running package count from the memory of MsDtsSrvr.exe.

If the server runs continuously with a huge load of packages for a certain period the MsDtsSrvr memory will overflow which result in the **ArithmeticOverflow** Exception

**Solution:**
We need to release the MsDtsSrvr memory.So we need to restart the SSIS Service or restart the **MsDtsServer110** service (which will be running in the background)